# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException - SQLITE ERROR

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Please provide me a possible solution for this error.

```
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 2
at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
at com.freedomkitchen.sonali.freedomkitchenAndroidApp.DB_Access.GetRecipes(DB_Access.java:241)
at com.freedomkitchen.sonali.freedomkitchenAndroidApp.User_Ingredients_Input.ViewRecipes(User_Ingredients_Input.java:227)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
```

And here is the code.

```
public ArrayList<String> GetRecipes(String meal_cat_selected) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   // Cursor cursor_recipes = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + RECIPE_NAME + " FROM " + RECIPES_TABLE_NAME + " where " + MEAL_CATEGORY+"=?", new String[]{meal_cat_selected});
     Cursor cursor_recipes = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + RECIPE_NAME + " FROM " + RECIPES_TABLE_NAME + " where " + MEAL_CATEGORY+"= '"+meal_cat_selected+"'", null);
    ArrayList<String> array_list_recipes = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (cursor_recipes.isAfterLast() == false) {
        array_list_recipes.add(cursor_recipes.getString(cursor_recipes.getColumnIndex(RECIPE_NAME)));
        cursor_recipes.moveToNext();
        Log.i("reci_based_on_meal_cat", cursor_recipes.getString(cursor_recipes.getColumnIndex(RECIPE_NAME)));
    }
    db.close();
    return array_list_recipes;
}
```

Comment: Post your code of User_Ingredients_Input.java: line no 227

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move up string `Log.i("reci_based_on_meal_cat", cursor_recipes.getString(cursor_recipes...`

or move down `cursor_recipes.moveToNext();`

Answer (score 1):

You must move the cursor to the next record **one line BEFORE**.

```
cursor_recipes.moveToNext();
array_list_recipes.add(cursor_recipes.getString(cursor_recipes.getColumnIndex(RECIPE_NAME)));
```

Actually, you are trying to use it while it's still located at position **-1**.